# Error: undefined method 'x' for Nil (compile-time type is (Point | Nil))

Tags: unit-testing, compiler-errors, crystal-lang

I'm writing a test that checks coordinates of a point to have a certain value, e.g.:

```
it "should work" do
   p = do_something   # returns a Point(x, y)
   p.x.should eq 0    # errors (see below)
end
```

But it fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error: undefined method 'x' for Nil (compile-time type is (Point | Nil))
```

I was able to reduce the issue to the following minimal example which does not compile:

```
struct Point
    property x : Int32
    property y : Int32
    def initialize(@x, @y)
    end
end

begin
    p = Point.new 0, 0
ensure
    p.x == 0
end
```

Which throws the same error:

```
❯ crystal src/debug.cr
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In src/debug.cr:11:7

 11 | p.x == 0
        ^
Error: undefined method 'x' for Nil (compile-time type is (Point | Nil))
```

Now, I came across a similar bug report on the programming language Github tracker: [Nil type check fails when using ensure](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6002), apparently this is an issue that has to be addressed by the Crystal language.

My question is, how can I check the value of `p.x` without triggering this error in an `ensure` block? I'm kind of clueless how to access this.

For context, I'm writing a cryptographic library which operates on points on the an elliptic curve, so it's everything about checking the coordinates here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a couple of possibilities here, e.g. you can replace the line `p.x == 0` with either of:

1. `p.try &.x == 0` - `p` will be checked for being `Nil`, and only when it's not `Nil`, the comparison will run.
2. `p.not_nil!.x == 0` - you command the compiler that `p` can never be `Nil`, but if it actually happens to be `nil`, the line will raise at runtime.

Comment: Gotcha that worked. I figured that `p.x == 0 if !p.nil?` also did the trick.

Comment: @Afr `p.x == 0 if p` is also equivalent here, since `nil` is falsey. The compiler error is correct here, `Point.new` could raise an exception, in which case `p` would never be set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler can't know if the variable is actually defined in the ensure block, what if some something in your `Point` constructor threw an exception?

Consider this:

```
def m
  raise "foo"
  bar = 0
ensure
  bar += 1
end
```

In Crystal it's a compile time error, in Ruby (and similar languages) it would become a runtime error.